# Нарушена верстка

Tags: html, jquery, css

Не могу понять почему нарушена верстка.
Есть форма

```
<div class="cartUserContacts" style="height: 254px;">
        <form>
            <p>
                Введите Ф.И.О.<br>
                <input type="text" name="name">
            </p>
            <p>
                Контактный телефон<br>
                <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="+7 (_ _ _) _ _ _ - _ _ - _ _">
            </p>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Наименование компании<br>
                    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="ТОО или ИП">
                </p>
                <p>
                    Наименование компании<br>
                    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="ТОО или ИП">
                </p>
                <p>
                    Наименование компании<br>
                    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="ТОО или ИП">
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.cartUserContacts {
    width: 315px;
    float: left;
    border: solid 1px #c1c1c1;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Но высота форму больше чем div. Пишу Overflow:hidden не работает. В чем может быть проблема. Ниже предоставляю принтсрин и ссылку. Левый блок видно как заходит на футтер. [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [Ссылка на сайт](http://technomarket.kz/cart) Только для того что бы корзина появилась нужно добавить товар.

Comment: Насколько вижу, проблему решили. Расскажите как. Кстати, если убрать высоту - то отлично отодвигает хедер.

Comment: В точку, проблема в высоте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
<div class="cartUserContacts" style="height: 100%;">
    <form>
        <p>
            Введите Ф.И.О.<br>
            <input type="text" name="name">
        </p>
        <p>
            Контактный телефон<br>
            <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="+7 (_ _ _) _ _ _ - _ _ - _ _">
        </p>
        <div>
            <p>
                Наименование компании<br>
                <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="ТОО или ИП">
            </p>
            <p>
                Наименование компании<br>
                <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="ТОО или ИП">
            </p>
            <p>
                Наименование компании<br>
                <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="ТОО или ИП">
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Удачного кодинга...